# Pasar valores de latitud y longitud a formulario

Tags: google-maps, formularios

Tengo una página que me despliega un mapa en donde localiza mi posición de forma automática, he intentado a través de otro código pasar la latitud y longitud a un formulario en campos de texto, pero no lo he logrado.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 50%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 50%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    

<form action="">
 <input name="lat" id="lat">
    <input name="lng" id="lng">
</form>    
    
    
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 6
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude };
     
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      }
   

   
   
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxxx&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que quieres, poner las coordenadas que te autodetecta que estás en un ' <input>?

Comment: poner un un campo latitud y en otro longitud de las coordenadas detectadas

Comment: @PedroJimenez prueba con mi respuesta, y si te ayudo marcala como correcta por favor. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es "injectar" los datos usando el id con la función `getElementById`, en tu caso:

```
document.getElementById("lat").value = pos['lat'];
document.getElementById("lng").value = pos['lng'];
```

El ejemplo completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 50%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 50%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    

<form action="">
 <input name="lat" id="lat">
    <input name="lng" id="lng">
</form>    
    
    
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 6
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude 
          };
     
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            document.getElementById("lat").value = pos['lat'];
            document.getElementById("lng").value = pos['lng'];
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      }
   

   
   
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, esra lo que necesitaba exactamente

Comment: por favor no te olvides de marca mi respuesta como correcta :P

Comment: ya lo hice pero no se ve porque tengo menos de 15 puntos :(

Comment: @PedroJimenez Una cosa es dar puntos y otra cosa es marcar la respuesta como correcta, debajo de mi puntaje de esta pregunta hay un check que debes apretar, para ello no necesitas puntaje, esto solo lo puede hacer solo el autor. Por favor revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, alli te indican como marcar la respuesta como correcta, gracias :P

Comment: ok, gracias,ya lo hice, no tenia ni idea de ello y por eso marcaba en el puntaje de la respuesta

Comment: Trata de  hacer lo mismo con tus demás preguntas :P